# Delete and then Add over 75000 Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a list of info that is updated monthly from an outside source that has over 75000 rows of data. The data comes in Excel.

I see that this table has a list that has been updated multiple times in SQL Server as the current one has 75000 rows of data but the IDs are in the 900000's. What is the best way to delete the current data and insert the most up to date? I selected all of the rows and hit delete but it froze up SQL Server.

Comment: What you are *actually* trying to achieve here? If you want to "delete" all the data in the existing table and reimport it all, you could `TRUNCATE` the table first; that would be much faster than a `DELETE`. If, however, you have any kind of Foreign Keys, then a `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` won't work; you'd be better off looking at `BULK INSERT`ing the data into a staging table and then doing an UPSERT.

Comment: In truth though, as it stands your question lacks focus; you need to tell us what you're specifically struggling with. Asking "What is best" is far to open ended and opinionated for [so].

Comment: "selected all of the rows and hit delete" sounds like you might be using a UI that deletes all the rows one by one? This would be pretty much the slowest possible way

Comment: To reset the table as new--assuming you do not need any of its data at all--look at using `TRUNCATE TABLE`.

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow please get tour here https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read help center for give best feedback